# To store search engine results in Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database

We have to store the first 20 search engine results (URLS and id) in the Mysql database. We referred to the google search API, it says we will get results in JSOn/ATOM format, but we are not getting exactly how to store those results in JSON format (httptitle, snippet etc attributes) into the database. Do we need to do parsing? Actually it is  a module of the project so can we do it without any parsing? As in how to pass parameters on JSON into the table in the database.

Comment: JSON is a data-format ,the way Google returning the results to you.But it must be giving you lot of information beside what you want to store  in DB.better parse the JSON and get only the data you need to store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a Java JSON Library which lets you parse json string to java objects and vice versa(See [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)). Then you can extract the required information from those objects and store them in database. Your database table should have columns like search engine name, query string, url, id etc.